# Cannot fetch data from an API using componentDidMount: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React. I've used it for building a very simple app. I'm trying to add a small feature, but running into following error message. I don't quite understand the root cause yet.

`Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Here's what I'm trying to do. My app has a backend server that provides various APIs, which returns JSON. I'm using React as frontend/client that calls those APIs and renders them.

I have a Parent component named `MyReport` which uses `componentDidMount` to call an API to fetch some data. Then in the render method, I pass the data to  another component named `MyReportViewer`. This component has various other child components such as a Calendar that allows selecting date, a component that shows the data in a table format, a component that shows the same data as a chart.

Now I'm trying to add another child component called `MyReportSummary` that will be displayed alongside the other components rendered by `MyReportViewer`.

`MyReportSummary` needs to call another API to fetch some data. This is what it looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyReportSummary extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectInfo: null,
            isLoading: false,
            error: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        let projectInfoApi;

        projectInfoApi = '/api/projects/' + this.props.projectId;

        fetch(projectInfoApi)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Encountered problem fetching project info')
                }
            })
            .then(data => this.setState({
                projectInfo: data
            }))
            .catch(fetchError => this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                error: fetchError
            }));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // this.setState({
        //     projectInfo: null
        // });
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, error } = this.state;

        if (error) {
            return <p>{error.message}</p>
        }

        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>
        }

        return (
            <div className="myReportSummary">
                 Summary of Project name: {projectInfo.name}                    
                 Number of events: {this.props.data.length}
            </div>
        );
  }
}

export default MyReportSummary;
```

I've read that I need to use `componentWillUnmount` to reset everything, but I'm not sure what exactly I need to reset here and why in this case I need to do it because I don't think I'm trying to change the component after it's been loaded or rendered already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning indicates that your component has been unmounted before you get a chance to handle the response of your fetch.

You can keep a property on your component outside of state called e.g. `isMounted` and set that to `false` in `componentWillUnmount` and check if it's `true` when your fetch has completed:

**Example**

```
class MyReportSummary extends Component {
  mounted = true;
  state = {
    projectInfo: null,
    isLoading: true,
    error: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/api/projects/${this.props.projectId}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Encountered problem fetching project info");
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (this.mounted) {
          this.setState({
            projectInfo: data
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(fetchError => {
        if (this.mounted) {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            error: fetchError
          });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, error, projectInfo } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="myReportSummary">
        Summary of Project name: {projectInfo.name}
        Number of events: {this.props.data.length}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Not sure if I did something wrong, but I'm getting the error: `TypeError: Cannot set property isMounted of #<Component> which has only a getter new MergeReportSummary`.

Comment: @aver Sorry about that. I totally forgot that `isMounted` is used by React when I wrote the example... I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle. That did get me further but I still could not parse the json data stored in `projectInfo` and then display `projectInfo.name` in the `render` method. I get a message `body stream already read` being rendered by this component. Chrome debugger/developer tool shows me the fetched data as a **promise**, which is in resolved state. And I can manually parse that resolved data. Also, I noticed that I can't have `mounted` property/variable inside the constructor.

Comment: @aver That's frustrating. Since the error in the question has been resolved, maybe open up a new question including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I just found out the root of that error. I had added `console.log(response.json())` before returning `response.json()`. It turns out I cannot convert the response to json twice like that. Unfortunately now I'm getting a different compile error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`. It's coming from the render method where I'm trying to print out the project name `{projectInfo.name}`. I'll resolve this question and try to figure it out before posting again. If you notice the issue, please let me know.

Comment: @aver Try to log the `data` inside `if (this.mounted) { ... }`. It might be that the `data` is `null`, which would give rise to your error.

Comment: I was able to find out why I have that error. That bring up a new question, which I just posted now.I hope you'll have some time to help me understand this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368442/reactjs-storing-state-in-constructor-vs-property