# reactjs storing state in constructor vs property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple react component that needs to connect to an API and retrieve some JSON data, which will then be used for displaying some information.

In the following class/component, I have `mounted` and `state` as a property. I normally use a constructor to hold my states but in this case, if I move the state to a constructor, I cannot seem to access the data (`projectInfo`) inside the renderer. When inside the renderer (line containinig `{projectInfo.name}`), I get the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

How can I use the constructor in this class to hold the state? Why does the following class work but not when I use a constructor? What is the convention for handling something like this?

```
class MyReportSummary extends Component {
  mounted = true;
  state = {
    projectInfo: null,
    isLoading: true,
    error: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/api/projects/${this.props.projectId}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error("Encountered problem fetching project info");
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (this.mounted) {
          this.setState({
            projectInfo: data
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(fetchError => {
        if (this.mounted) {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            error: fetchError
          });
        }
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, error, projectInfo } = this.state;

    if (error) {
      return <p>{error.message}</p>;
    }

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div className="myReportSummary">
        Summary of Project name: {projectInfo.name}
        Number of events: {this.props.data.length}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Just for clarity, the above sample code works just fine. What I'm trying to understand is if my class look like this that has a constructor initializing state, then I get that *TypeError*.

```
class MyReportSummary extends Component {
  mounted = true;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        projectInfo: null,
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // same as the previous sample code
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    //same as the previous sample code
  }
}
```

What is the correct convention for states? Is `constructor` not the proper way of doing this?

Comment: You are missing the `constructor` function and you will need to initialize `this.state` in the constructor function.

Comment: @Hoyen That's called [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/) and is perfectly valid.

Comment: it's because it's trying to render before your fetch promise finishes, accessing `.name` on the default `null` object. set the default `state.projectInfo` to an empty object `{}` and you should be fine.

Comment: Could you include the `data` you get from the API in the question?

Comment: [This simple example works, with a fake `fetch`](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjnxj44rp7). It might give some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle for the sample and your help so far. I updated the description of this question. I hope that clarifies what I'm asking.

Comment: @aver Ah, now I understand. That's odd. Are you sure you are writing it like that? I updated the example in that link, and that works as well.

Comment: @aver Ah, now I see the error. You are initializing `isLoading` to false. If `error` in `null`, `isLoading` is `false`, then you will hit the last part of your render method. Since `projectInfo` is `null` before your request is complete, you will try to access `name` on `null` and get your error. Set `isLoading` to `true` and it should work as expected, or even `projectInfo` to an empty object `{}`, but then you will not get the `Loading...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing state in the constructor like your second example is perfectly valid, but your two examples are not the same. You are setting `isLoading` to `true` in the class property version, but `isLoading` to `false` in the constructor.

If `error` in `null` and `isLoading` is `false` you will hit the last part of your render method. Since `projectInfo` is `null` before your request is complete, you will try to access `name` on `null` and get your error.

Set `isLoading` to `true` and it should work as expected, or even `projectInfo` to an empty object `{}`, but then you will not get the loading indicator.

```
class MyReportSummary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.mounted = true;
    this.state = {
      projectInfo: {},
      isLoading: true,
      error: null
    };
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it!! Thanks a lot for all the help. I did not realize that loading flag was causing all the problem.

Comment: @aver You're welcome! It happens to all of us. It's easy to miss those things